# Amazon Elastic Mapreduce default configurations

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, emr

Are the Hadoop configuration defaults (core-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, etc) published by Amazon? I've seen select parameters published but not the total default configurations.

Comment: You can launch an `m1.small` cluster (as I remember it's free) and fetch configuration from `/home/hadoop/conf`.

Comment: UPD: Some config depends on instance type.

Comment: @mr0re1 You're correct, except for the fact there are no free tier eligible emr configuration, and one have to pay some few cents for launching a cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will find defaults config at amazon emr documentation page at below link
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/TaskConfiguration_H2.html

There is way you can find config for job that is triggerd. You can visit to S3 Location where logs are saved. There you will find j-yourjoblogsfilelocation/jobs/job_1403597560615_0001_conf.xml. The _conf.xml has all config that are passed to job. They are the defaults config unless we overwrite them. So this will be different as per box config we choose. e.g memory configs may be different

Comment: Thanks Sandesh -- I've seen these but they're not complete. There are several hundred Hadoop default configs and I can find only maybe 15 documented AWS EMR configs.

Comment: There is way you can find config for job that is triggerd. You can visit to S3 Location where logs are saved. There you will find j-yourjoblogsfilelocation/jobs/job_1403597560615_0001_conf.xml. The _conf.xml has all config that are passed to job. They are the defaults config unless we overwrite them. So this will be different as per box config we choose. e.g memory configs may be different. Hope this will help.